# Hystrix Dashboarding in Node.js Services?

Tags: hystrix, hystrix-dashboard

Is there any functionality in Node.js to stream hystrix events from Node.js services to monitor it on a dashboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to guess you're a Java developer who's now doing Node and looking for an equivalent solution to Hystrix and Hystrix Dashboard in the Node ecosystem. So you're looking for a *circuit breaker* library that supports *monitoring*. There's not a single solution in the Node world that does all of this, but my bet would be on:

- [oppossum](https://www.npmjs.com/package/opossum) for the circuit-breaker pattern
- [Prometheus](https://prometheus.io/) as a general purpose monitoring solution
- [Grafana](https://grafana.com/) as a general purpose visualization solution
- [opossum-prometheus](https://github.com/nodeshift/opossum-prometheus) to push metrics from the circuit-breaker to Prometheus

Example code as seen on the [opossum-prometheus GitHub page](https://github.com/nodeshift/opossum-prometheus)

```
  const CircuitBreaker = require('opossum');
  const PrometheusMetrics = require('opossum-prometheus');

  // create a couple of circuit breakers
  const c1 = new CircuitBreaker(someFunction);
  const c2 = new CircuitBreaker(someOtherfunction);

  // Provide them to the constructor
  const prometheus = new PrometheusMetrics({ circuits: [c1, c2] });

  //...
  // Provide other circuit breaker later
  const c3 = new CircuitBreaker(someOtherfunction3);
  prometheus.add([C3]);

  // Write metrics to the console
  console.log(prometheus.metrics);
```

In Grafana this will look like this:

[image: Grafana dashboard showing the events emitted by a circuit breaker at different rates of error.]

Here is a [Medium article](https://medium.com/better-programming/monitor-node-js-circuit-breakers-using-opossum-and-prometheus-5c66d516de3d) explaining how to set up this stack in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

yep, opossum circuit breaker + [opossum-hystrix](https://github.com/nodeshift/opossum-hystrix)

also try opossum + [opossum-prometheus](https://github.com/nodeshift/opossum-prometheus)

opossum is a widely used well documented circuit breaker implementation
and and there are some plugins that allow you to send metrics to services like prometheus and hystrix-dashboard